# Techniques or Utilities to Print a SharePoint 2010 workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

Does anyone know of a technique, method or utility to print a SharePoint 2010 workflow, including the approval process(s) and e-mail definition(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting it in Visio 2010, but it wont contain the object properties

Answer (score 0):

I select-all in SharePoint Designer and then I paste it into notepad.
The formatting is tabbed, but string builders are truncated and additional properties are not visible (sounds like what Raymund is experiencing)